# expected expression error in nested if statement c++

Tags: c++

I keep getting an expected expression error in my nested if else statement. I don't understand what the problem is because I have other statements in the code that are formatted (as far as I can see) the exact same way that don't generate the error!

This is for an assignment in a first year c++ class that calculates bowling scores based on user input data.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Set Variables
    int userin_1;
    int userin_2;
    int userin_3;
    int combined2_3;
    int score;


    // Query User

    cout << "Welcome to Josh's Bowling Score Calculator! " << "Please enter your three scores. "
    << "They should be between 0 and 10." << endl << endl;

    cin >> userin_1 >> userin_2 >> userin_3;

    // Verify input data

    if (userin_1 <= 10 && userin_2 <=10 && userin_3 <=10)
        userin_1 = userin_1;
        else cout << endl << "Input Error: You cannot score greater than 10 in one turn! :|" << endl;

    if (userin_1 >= 0 && userin_2 >=0 && userin_3 >=0)
        userin_1 = userin_1;
    else cout << endl << "Input Error: You cannot score less than 0 in one turn! :|" << endl;

    if (userin_1 == 10)
        userin_1 = userin_1;
        else if (userin_1 + userin_2 <= 10)
            cout << "Input Error: You can't score more than 10 on your first two throws unless your first throw is a strike! "
            << endl;

    if (userin_2 == 10)
        userin_2 = userin_2;
    else if (userin_2 + userin_3 <= 10)
        cout << "Input Error: You can't score more than 10 on your first two throws unless your first throw is a strike! "
        << endl;

    // Calculate Score

    combined2_3 = userin_2 + userin_3;

    if (userin_1 + userin_2 < 10)
    {
        score = userin_1 + userin_2;
        cout << "Because you scored less than 10 on your first two throws, your last score doesn't count :[ "
    << "Your score is: " << score << endl;
    }
        else
        {
        if (userin_1 == 10 && userin_2 == 10 && userin_3 == 10)
        score = userin_1 + userin_2 + userin_3;
        cout << "Wowow 3 strikes! Your score is " << score << endl;
        }
            else
            {
            if (userin_1 == 10 && userin_2 == 10)
            score = userin_1 + userin_2 + userin_3;
            cout << "Two strikes! Your score is " << score << endl;
            }
                else
                {
                if (userin_1 == 10 && userin_2 + userin_3 >= 10)
                    cout << "It's not possible to score greater than 10 on your last two throws, unless your first throw is a strike :| " << endl;
                }
                    else
                    {
                        if (userin_1 == 10 && combined2_3 >= 10)
                            score = userin_1 + userin_2 + userin_3;
                        cout << "Nice, a strike! Your score is " << score << endl;
                    }
                        else
                        {
                            if (userin_1 == 0 && userin_2 == 0 && userin_3 == 0)
                                cout << "Donny, you're out of your element. All zeroes." << endl << endl;
                        }


    // Closing Statement

    cout << endl << "Thanks for bowling with me, hope you have a great day";




}
```

Comment: You have (too) many levels of nesting and inconsistent/bad indentation. It would be very helpful to us (and mostly to you) to properly indent your code.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: This also isn't the problem, but learn DeMorgan's theorem so that you don't have to write code like `if (userin_1 <= 10 && userin_2 <=10 && userin_3 <=10) userin_1 = userin_1; else whatever();`. You can write it like this: `if (userin_1 > 10 || userin_2 > 10 || userin_3 > 10) whatever();`.

Comment: A good editor/IDE can help with indentation and balancing of curly braces and make the source of this kind of problem pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I was wrong, here's the error:

```
    else
    {
    if (userin_1 == 10 && userin_2 == 10 && userin_3 == 10)
    score = userin_1 + userin_2 + userin_3;
    cout << "Wowow 3 strikes! Your score is " << score << endl;
    }
        else
        {
        if (userin_1 == 10 && userin_2 == 10)
        score = userin_1 + userin_2 + userin_3;
        cout << "Two strikes! Your score is " << score << endl;
        }
```

The second `else` has no associated `if` before it. Move the `if`'s into the corresponding `else` clauses.

```
    else if (userin_1 == 10 && userin_2 == 10 && userin_3 == 10) {
        score = userin_1 + userin_2 + userin_3;
        cout << "Wowow 3 strikes! Your score is " << score << endl;
    } else if (userin_1 == 10 && userin_2 == 10) {
        score = userin_1 + userin_2 + userin_3;
        cout << "Two strikes! Your score is " << score << endl;
    }
```

However, the more serious problem here is the way you approach the task. There are way too many nested `if` statements for this task. You repeat yourself a few times on the conditions, whereas the proper way would be to only check the condition once and then branch off.

Also, statements like

```
if (userin_1 <= 10 && userin_2 <=10 && userin_3 <=10)
    userin_1 = userin_1;
```

make no sense, you should instead check for the opposite and skip the `else` clause altogether.

You should also use proper indentation, as it greatly helps to improve code readability and helps avoid errors like these.

Comment: Who left a -1, please explain.

Comment: The OP asked for the error in the code, I found it. Please revoke.  I think the OP doesn't understand how if-else works is the reason, not the coding style.

Comment: Not a chance. The OP probably doesn't even know that he could find it himself trivially by just not writing such bad code to begin with. You're supposed to actually help him.

Comment: Well, in a sense I agree. Give me some time to mention that.

Comment: @Puppy any better? Short of rewriting the code completely, which I don't think is a good thing to do, that's my answer.